# table sorting in groups

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

I have table with folders first and then documents. I want to sort such that sorting applies to both the folders and documents but want to keep sorted folders first and then sorted documents. Is it possible with jQuery table sorter? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [tablesorter documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/).  You can manually sort by clicking one column, holding shift, and clicking other columns.  Or you can code in a default sort by setting configuration options - the example in documentation to sort by first and second columns in ascending order is:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter( {sortList: [[0,0], [1,0]]} ); 
    } 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx very much for your reply.I went for sortForce: [[0,0]] option in jquery.tablesorter.js.Added one  as first columns for both folders and documents.
For folders  and for documents ..

This solved my problem.

Thanx again
Dushyant Joshi